# Checkboxgroup change columns -> re-render

Tags: extjs

I have a checkbox group with predefined

```
columns : 6,
```

and a resize event

```
listeners: {
    resize:function( mee, width, height, e, eOpts ) {
        console.log(me.columns);
        console.log(mee.columns);
        mee.columns = Math.floor(width/200);
        // mee.doAutoRender();
        console.log(me.columns);
        console.log(mee.columns);
        console.log('resize');
    }
```

The console logging shows that both me.columns and mee.columns are 6 before and 9 after first resize (full-hd screen -> floor(1920/200)=9)

But I don't know how to enforce a re-rendering. The columns are not changing as I would like them to.

Comment: Just tell, what you want?

Comment: The checkbox group should have variable column count depending on available width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set layout: 'column'. Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/TNgTG/

```
var checkboxGroup = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    id: 'CheckboxGroup',
    width: 180,
    title: 'Checkbox Group',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items:[{
        xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
        layout: 'column',
        items: [
            { boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1' },
            { boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2', checked: true },
            { boxLabel: 'Item 3', name: 'rb', inputValue: '3' },
            { boxLabel: 'Item 4', name: 'rb', inputValue: '4' },
            { boxLabel: 'Item 5', name: 'rb', inputValue: '5' }
        ]
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.resizer.Resizer', {
    el: 'CheckboxGroup',
    handles: 'all',
    pinned: true,
    listeners: {
        resize: function(me, width, height){
            checkboxGroup.setSize(width, height);
        }
    }
});
```

[image]
[image]